# Linux kernel printk can skip messages?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, circular-buffer, printk

i see that in `vprintk_emit` kernel puts messages into `log_buffer` and then print them `console_unlock->call_console_driver`. But in case if we will put more messages than console (UART) could actually transmitt - what will be the behaviour? I see no blocking primitives near putting messages to log_buffer, so does it mean we will just delete some messages in the beginning of the log_buf to put some new (ring buffer)? So does it mean that printk messages could be lost? I'am talking about kernel 4.1
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L1613